# Highlight PHP syntax in .html extensions in VIM

Tags: php, vim

I am working on a codebase that uses php within .html files. How do I tell VIM to highlight php correctly in .html files without renaming all of my .html to .php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alec led me in the right direction as to what to look for, but I was looking for a hardcoded solution in the vimrc file. I went ahead with this:

```
augroup filetype
        autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead <Directory Path>/*.html set filetype=php
augroup END
```

This changes all files within the codebase to php for highlighting

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps with `:set filetype`?

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_06.html

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but this worked for me:
set ft=php.html

This tells VIM to highlight using the syntax for both filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for your `.vimrc` file:

```
:au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html set filetype=php
```